# Routing via RedirectToRouteResult content is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, asp.net-routing

I'm having a strange one, i have a attribute which performs the job seen bellow, but the strange part is that the controller hit/accepting, dot get the model.

```
return new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
{
    controller = controller,
    action = action,
    model = new LoginUserModel()
    {
        flowPartial = true,
        gotoController = (string)rData.Values["controller"],
        gotoAction = (string)rData.Values["action"],
        formData = formDatas
    }
}));
```

Here model is null

```
public ActionResult LoadPartialWithModel(LoginUserModel model)
{
    return PartialView("~/Views/Partials/_Login.cshtml", model);
}
```

Comment: How do you expect the `LoginUserModel` data to be passed over redirection?

Comment: Actually, i was hoping for it to go internally, but i assume it should be in a formbody of some sort. I'm not too experienced with routing, so it all comes down to i have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can work. A redirect result will send a HTPP 301 to the browser with a new url that will then be requested by the browser as GET request. There is no way to encode a complex model as a parameter of your get request. This is supported by model binding in a post but if you look at the details it gets fairly long. 
One thing you could do is to have your second method accept simple parameters

```
public ActionResult LoadPartialWithModel(bool flowPartial, string controller, ....)
```

and then in your redirectToRoute pass them as route values individually. This should create a nice URL with the parameters in the query string to which the browser can redirect

This is assuming you need to go via the browser, because if this is not required you are allowed to call the other controller method directly

```
return LoadPartialWithModel (new LoginUserModel()
{
    flowPartial = true,
    gotoController = (string)rData.Values["controller"],
    gotoAction = (string)rData.Values["action"],
    formData = formDatas
});
```